# Model creation within timezone with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, google-maps-api-3, timezone

So... I'm trying to create things on a map.  There's a date and time associated with the thing, but it's currently saving 1:1.  So, if I save something and give it a date of `2013-11-28 @ 12:00 pm`, it saves to the database with that specific time.  It should be saving UTC... so `2013-11-28 @ 18:00 pm` in my case.

I have an around_filter for timezone...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter :user_time_zone, if: :current_user

private

  def user_time_zone(&block)
    Time.use_zone(current_user.location, &block)
  end
end
```

So, once the thing is saved... it is properly time zoned, and displays as `2013-11-28 @ 04:00 am`.

I'd like to use the Time.use_zone function when setting the time, but that doesn't work either.  I am using google to get the time zone of where the thing is on the map...

```
JSON.load(open("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=#{params[:lat]},#{params[:lng]}&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=false"))["timeZoneId"]
```

gets me the proper timezone... but I can't seem to apply it during the save.  It might have to do with the model?  I have separate fields for date and time... and I combine them in the model:

```
before_create :convert_to_start

# Start
def startDate
  start.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") if start.present?
end 
def startDate=(date)
  # Change back to datetime friendly format
  @startDate = Date.parse(date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end
def startTime
  start.strftime("%I:%M%p") if start.present?
end
def startTime=(time)
  # Change back to datetime friendly format
  @startTime = Time.parse(time).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
end

def convert_to_start
  self.start = DateTime.parse("#{@startDate} #{@startTime}")
end
```

I'm thinking I need to pass the timezone that I get from google to those methods in the model, but I can't seem to figure out how to interact with them.

Comment: Chronic gem is the answer... I was trying to stick with native rails stuff, but Chronic is just too awesome.  `Chronic.time_class = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.create(#timezone fetched by google)`, then in the model, all those parses change to `Chronic.parse`.  All of them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chronic gem solves this issue.

```
tz = JSON.load(open("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=#{params[:event][:lat]},#{params[:event][:lng]}&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=false"))["timeZoneId"]
Chronic.time_class = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.create(tz)
```

Then in the model... all those parses become

```
def startDate=(date)
  # Change back to datetime friendly format
  @startDate = Chronic.parse(date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end
```